# ASP.NET Core Navigation Properties For Mapping Table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a table called contracts which has the id of entity 1 and entity 2. I use this to create links between entities, however I can't seem to get the definition of the dbContext correct. I can get the contracts to load but only one entity. When I view the contract either Entity1 is loaded or Entity2 is loaded but never both.

The models look like this:

```
 public class Contract
    {
        public int Entity1ID { get; set; }
        public int Entity2ID { get; set; }

        public Entity Entity1 { get; set; }

        public Entity Entity2 { get; set; }
    }
```

My entity class looks like this

```
public class Entity 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contract> Contracts1 { get; set; };
    public ICollection<Contract> Contracts2 { get; set; };
}
```

This is my dbContext

```
public class EntityDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public EntityDbContext(DbContextOptions<EntityDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
        {


        }

        public DbSet<Models.Entity> Entities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Models.Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
                .HasKey(n => n.ID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
               .HasKey(n => new { n.Entity1ID, n.Entity2ID });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasOne(n => n.Entity1)
                .WithMany(n => n.Contracts1)
                .HasForeignKey(n => n.Entity1ID);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasOne(n => n.Entity2)
                .WithMany(n => n.Contracts2)
                .HasForeignKey(n => n.Entity2ID);

        }

    }
```

Comment: What’s your exact issue?

Comment: When I view the contract either Entity1 is loaded or Entity2 is loaded but never both.

Comment: Can you show the code, where you try to load the entities.

Comment: After some more playing around I think this might be a lazy loading issue. If load all the contracts and entities before I queries the data then all the references are there.

Comment: maybe try loading them explicitly by using EF Core's `.Include()` extension method

Answer (score 0):

From your model design , there is a self-referencing many-to-many relationship in `Entity` model , so you should change DeleteBehavior to Restrict(the default is cascade) like below:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity>()
            .HasKey(n => n.ID);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
           .HasKey(n => new { n.Entity1ID, n.Entity2ID });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasOne(n => n.Entity1)
            .WithMany(n => n.Contracts1)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.Entity1ID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
            .HasOne(n => n.Entity2)
            .WithMany(n => n.Contracts2)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.Entity2ID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
    }
```

For [loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) , you could use the `Include` method that Sharif suggested above to specify related data to be included in query results

```
var result = _context.Contracts
            .Include(c => c.Entity1)
            .Include(c => c.Entity2)
            .ToList();
```

Result
[image]